# Memory access violation in C

Tags: c, runtime-error, memory-access

I've created a periodic table program in C, with an dynamic field, or at least I tried.

I will extend the program later, with the other 116 elements, but for now, it will be like this.

Compiler says nothing, but I get a runtime error: 'memory access violation'

What did I overlooked/miss?

The Output should only show the saved elements (Aluminium/Radium).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


  typedef struct
  {
    char Name[20];
    char Symbol[3];
    char Atomicnumber[5];
    char* entrys;
  } Element;


int main(void)
{
    //Define the two entrys/elements

    Element Aluminium;
    strcpy(Aluminium.Name, "Aluminium");
    strcpy(Aluminium.Symbol, "Al");
    strcpy(Aluminium.Atomicnumber, "13");

    Element Radium;
    strcpy(Radium.Name, "Radium");
    strcpy(Radium.Symbol, "Ra");
    strcpy(Radium.Atomicnumber, "88");

    int size=0;
    //Define field
    printf ("size of field:");
    scanf( "%d" , &size);
    //Gives the saved Elements an Adress in Array/Field  

    Element Periodictable [size];

    strcpy(Periodictable[13].Name, "Aluminium");
    strcpy(Periodictable[13].Symbol, "Al");
    strcpy(Periodictable[13].Atomicnumber, "13");
    strcpy(Periodictable[13].entrys, "1");

    strcpy(Periodictable[88].Name, "Radium");
    strcpy(Periodictable[88].Symbol, "Ra");
    strcpy(Periodictable[88].Atomicnumber, "88");
    strcpy(Periodictable[88].entrys, "1");

    void output(Element* Periodictable, int*entry);

    printf("Recorded elements:\n");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i=1; i<= size; i++)
    {
        if (Periodictable[i].entrys)
        {
            printf("Name: %s \n",Periodictable[i].Name);
            printf("Symbol: %s \n",Periodictable[i].Symbol);
            printf("Atomic number: %s \n",Periodictable[i].Atomicnumber);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else i++;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

output should be like this:

```
Recorded elements:
Name: Aluminium
Symbol: Al
Atomic number: 13
Name: Radium
Symbol: Ra
Atomic number: 88
```

The defined field should still be created, but the empty fields/adresses should not be shown in the console

Comment: if size < 89 then you'll have a problem. What do you input as size?

Comment: `entrys` is a character pointer without any memory allocated to it. Therefore this line `strcpy(Periodictable[13].entrys, "1");` will fail

Comment: as a side note: I strongly suggest that you create a configuration file that you'll read instead of copying/pasting all the code to create the 116 elements.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - There are 118 elements now

Comment: @EdHeal how could I forget that ;) if you want my input, coffee should be a full fledged element.

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre            max. 118.
But before i got the last error message,during the programming,the sizevariable was not the problem, or at least , the compile didn't show anything wrong.

Comment: FYI, this is a runtime error, not a compile-time error.

Comment: `char* entrys;` is for a pointer to a string and not the memory for a string. Do you want `char entrys[4];` instead?

Comment: @Richard Chambers

changed, but still the same error

Comment: @EdHeal, he must have something against `Ununseptium` and `Ununoctium`...

Comment: The index to explore an array of `[size]` elements in **C** shall be from 0 to (size-1). The for-loop `for(int i=1; i<= size; i++)` shall be `for(int i=0; i< size; i++)`. And the else-case `else i++;` will hide the next Element.

Comment: Two changes. Make `Element Periodictable [size];` be `Element Periodictable [size] = {0};` to initialize it to all zeros. Change your test in the loop from `if (Periodictable[i].entrys)` to `if (Periodictable[i].entrys[0])`. Also fix your look control from `for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`. I assume your C compiler allows dynamic array allocation with the `Periodictable` array.

Comment: :43:5: error: variable sized object may not be initialized

Element Periodictable [size] ={0};

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. The `entrys` member is a pointer to `char` which never gets initialized or receives dynamically allocated memory. You have declared the other 3 members statically and initialized their values using `strcpy`. However, `strcpy` should not be used on unallocated pointers, as you could be writing to an arbitrary memory space outside the memory allocated for your program to run. *Memory access violation* #1.
2. You allocate `Periodictable` based on the user input. So, if the user inputs a number smaller than 89, you would be trying to access another memory space that could be out of bounds for your program when you reference `Periodictable[88]`. As you know the number of elements from the start, you could use a simple fixed array that would hold all 118 elements (thus of size 119 if you want to keep the array index by element number and ignore element 0). *Memory access violation* #2.
3. When you allocate the `Periodictable` array, you have forgotten to initialize it. Do remember that C does not initialize arrays by default, so you must do it yourself. A call to `memset()` over the whole array would do.
4. The `if (Periodictable[i].entrys)` will not work as you are not dereferencing the `entrys` pointer from your original implementation. If you decided to keep `entrys` as a pointer, you could write `if (*Periodictable[i].entrys)` instead. However, it doesn't seem to be necessary to use a pointer, instead a simple `char` could do the trick (actually a `bool` would even be more appropriate and more legible).
5. You are necessarily skipping an element with the `else i++` statement, it just didn't show yet because there are not enough elements registered in the array. You don't have to increase `i` again as the for loop already does that.
6. There are two styles of initialization in your code, and both could be made to work. One is to write values directly to the array, the other is to declare elements on the stack, write to them, and copy them to the array. In the code below the two elements are initialized differently as an example.

So, that's what the code would look like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 119

typedef struct
  {
    char Name[20];
    char Symbol[3];
    char Atomicnumber[5];
    char entrys;
  } Element;


int main(void)
{
    Element Periodictable [MAXSIZE];
    memset(&Periodictable, 0, sizeof(Element) * MAXSIZE);

    Element Aluminium;
    strcpy(Aluminium.Name, "Aluminium");
    strcpy(Aluminium.Symbol, "Al");
    strcpy(Aluminium.Atomicnumber, "13");
    Aluminium.entrys = 1;
    memcpy(&Periodictable[13], &Aluminium, sizeof(Element));

    strcpy(Periodictable[88].Name, "Radium");
    strcpy(Periodictable[88].Symbol, "Ra");
    strcpy(Periodictable[88].Atomicnumber, "88");
    Periodictable[88].entrys = 1;

    printf("Recorded elements:\n");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i=1; i<= MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        if (Periodictable[i].entrys)
        {
            printf("Name: %s \n",Periodictable[i].Name);
            printf("Symbol: %s \n",Periodictable[i].Symbol);
            printf("Atomic number: %s \n",Periodictable[i].Atomicnumber);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

And it outputs:

```
Recorded elements:

Name: Aluminium
Symbol: Al
Atomic number: 13

Name: Radium
Symbol: Ra
Atomic number: 88
```

Finally, these changes would make the current design work, but there are probably easier ways to design the same program depending on what you are looking for. Nonetheless I hope the answer helps explain what was going on.